# node-mysql res.json(rows) return quote with backslash

Tags: mysql, node.js, json

I'm trying to fetch JSON type data from Mysql in Node.js application via node-mysql module.

running this piece of code:

```
router.get('/getmatdom', function (req, res) {
 Materie.getmateriedomande(function(err,rows){
    if(err) {
        res.status(400).json(err);
    }
    else
    {
        res.json(rows);
    }
 });
});
```

and

```
getmateriedomande: function(callback)
{
    return db.query('select json_arrayagg(json_object(\'name\', m.name, \'domande\', '+
    '(select json_arrayagg(json_object(\'domanda\', d.name)) '+
    'from domande as d where d.materia = m.id ))) as materie from materie m', callback);
}
```

the result is:

```
[
{
    "materie": "[{\"name\": \"Psicologia dell'apprendimento\", \"domande\": [{\"domanda\": \"Il 'Me' si riferisce a:\"}, {\"domanda\": \"I rinforzi negativi:\"}]}, {\"name\": \"Teoria e metodi di progettazione e valutazione didattica\", \"domande\": null}, {\"name\": \"Didattica speciale\", \"domande\": null}]"
}
```

]

As you see there are backslash before each quote, but I don't want that backslash, how can I do it? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of asking how to remove backslash you should find out why it's there in first place.

It's there because you have double encoding.

The contents of `materie` are already JSON but you encode the whole thing again so in result you only have a single field `materie` with a large string.

Basically what happens is this:

```
res.json([{materie: "your mysql json result stringified"]);
```

IMO, it's not a good idea to work with JSON within MySQL. Working with fields and native stuff is safer for typing and encoding.

Solution:

Either remake your database stuff to not work with JSON stuff or simply don't double encode before sending data to your response. So instead of `res.json();` use `res.send();` with appropriate additional headers (`Content-Type`,..).

Comment: I modified the code with this line:

res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
res.send(rows);

but the backslash before each quote are still present. Why?

Comment: @GianfrancoVecchio then you'd have to JSON-decode the MySQL resonse beforehand. I don't know about those functions cause I work with classic stuff. Don't focus on the backslash, focus on the double encoding.